# Can I create symbolic links from a Yocto recipe for a file that doesn't exist yet

Tags: linux, embedded, symlink, yocto

I am running Yocto Pyro, and I am trying to create a recipe that creates a symlink to an area that will be mounted at runtime.  We are mounting our secondary storage at /var/local in the fstab.  I would like to store the network settings there since the rootFS gets wiped out when we do firmware upgrade of our devices.

This is the recipe I am working on.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Create links to the persistent storage area for the network files."
PRIORITY = "optional"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILES_${PN} += "/etc /etc/systemd/network"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    ln -frs /var/local/network/hostname ${D}/hostname
    ln -frs /var/local/network/eth0.network ${D}/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
#   ln -frs /var/local/network/sysctl.conf ${D}/etc/sysctl.conf
#   ln -frs /var/local/network/iptables-config ${D}/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
}
```

The error I am getting is that it is failing to create the symbolic link.

```
| ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev/tmp/work/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/network-links/1.0-r0/image/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network': No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/build-dev/tmp/work/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/network-links/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.118559)
ERROR: Task (/home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/meta-markem-imaje-private-bsp/recipes-core/network-links/network-links_1.0.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2805 tasks of which 2796 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/gen-ccm-root/workdir/tools/poky/meta-markem-imaje-private-bsp/recipes-core/network-links/network-links_1.0.bb:do_install
```

Is there a way to make the links?  Or do I need to take a different approach of reading the files at bootup and copying them in or something of that nature?  I do believe that the security team will eventually want to make the root filesystem read only, so links are preferred to modifying the RootFS at startup.

Comment: Using the `-r` parameter is not a good idea here, because `${D}` is a temporary path within yocto (the /image folder in the work folder of the recipe). The distance of the `image/` folder to `/` will most not match the distance of `/` to `/var` on the target system, so you will get a broken link on the target system. The shown error happens because you need to create `/etc/ystemd/network/` before being able to create a link in it (use `install -d`).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do that via extending base-files recipe via a bbappend

base-files_%.bbappend

```
do_install_append() {

...

}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, I still get the same error since the /var/local/ area won't be mounted until first boot of the device.  I am leaning towards it not being possible at this point.  I will have to write a script to do it at runtime

Answer (score 1):

What we do is create a postinstall function in .inc file in our image folder.

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += " symlinkfunction "

symlinkfunction() {
ln -s /path/on/target "${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/path/in/rootfs"
}
```

Use the .inc file in any image file that creates your target and it will update the target root file system with a new symlink.